# count from current row to last row

Tags: oracle

I have a requirement to pull the data in the below fashion.

```
progress_CMC_status    progress_cmc_status_numbers    cmc_status_numbers
Mature Draft                         2                         5
Review                               0                         3
Final Draft                          0                         3
Final Comment                        0                         3
Final Document                       2                         3
Archived Document                    1                         1
```

but i am getting output in different

```
progress_CMC_status    progress_cmc_status_numbers    cmc_status_numbers
Mature Draft                         2                         5
Review                               0                         0
Final Draft                          0                         0
Final Comment                        0                         0
Final Document                       2                         3
Archived Document                    1                         1
```

Tried the below code:

```
  WITH sta AS
  (SELECT 'Mature' "status1"
  FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'Review'
    FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'Final Draft'
    FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'Final Comment'
    FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'Final Document'
    FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'Archived'
    FROM DUAL)
  SELECT   DECODE ("stat",
             'Mature', 'Mature Draft',
             'Review', 'Review',
             'Final Draft', 'Final Draft',
             'Final Comment', 'Final Comment',
             'Final Document', 'Final Document',
             'Archived', 'Archived Document'
            ) AS "progress_CMC_status",
  NVL
        (TO_CHAR ("progress_cmc_status_numbers"),
         0
        ) AS "progress_cmc_status_numbers",
  NVL (TO_CHAR ("cmc_status_numbers"), 0) AS "cmc_status_numbers"
  FROM (SELECT "status1" AS "stat",
             NVL
                (TO_CHAR (NULL),
                 "progress_cmc_status_numbers"
                ) AS "progress_cmc_status_numbers",
             NVL (TO_CHAR (NULL),
                  "cmc_status_numbers"
                 ) AS "cmc_status_numbers"
   FROM sta
   LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT   VALUE AS "progress_CMC_status",
                       COUNT (*) AS "progress_cmc_status_numbers",
                       SUM (COUNT (*)) OVER (ORDER BY DECODE
                                                        (VALUE,
                                                         'Mature', 0,
                                                         'Review', 1,
                                                         'Final Draft', 2,
                                                         'Final Comment', 3,
                                                         'Final Document', 4,
                                                         'Archived', 5,
                                                         6
                                                        ) DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
                                                  AS "cmc_status_numbers"
                  FROM ATTRIBUTES
                 WHERE attribute_type_id IN (
                                            SELECT attribute_type_id
                                              FROM attribute_types
                                             WHERE name_display_code =
                                                                      'RD')
                   AND VALUE IN
                          ('Mature', 'Review', 'Final Draft',
                           'Final Comment', 'Final Document', 'Archived')
                   AND object_id IN (SELECT obj_id
                                       FROM docs)
              GROUP BY VALUE) a1 ON sta."status1" =
                                                  a1."progress_CMC_status"
             )
  ORDER BY DECODE ("progress_CMC_status",
             'Mature Draft', 0,
             'Review', 1,
             'Final Draft', 2,
             'Final Comment', 3,
             'Final Document', 4,
             'Archived Document', 5,
             6
            )
```

sample data

```
          CREATE TABLE ATTRIBUTES
         (
         object_id NUMBER(4),
         attribute_type_id NUMBER(4),
         name_display_code VARCHAR2(5),
         VALUE VARCHAR2(25)
          );

         begin
         insert into attributes values (101,201,'RMD','A100');
         insert into attributes values (102,201,'RMD','A200');
         insert into attributes values (103,201,'RMD','A300');
         insert into attributes values (104,200,'RD','Mature');
         insert into attributes values (105,200,'RD','Mature');
         insert into attributes values (106,200,'RD','Mature');
         insert into attributes values (107,200,'RD','Mature');
         insert into attributes values (108,200,'RD','Mature');
         insert into attributes values (109,200,'RD','Archived');
         insert into attributes values (110,200,'RD','Archived');
         insert into attributes values (111,200,'RD','Archived');
         insert into attributes values (112,200,'RD','Archived');
         insert into attributes values (113,200,'RD','Mature');
         insert into attributes values (114,200,'RD','Mature');
         insert into attributes values (115,200,'RD','Mature');
         insert into attributes values (116,200,'RD','Mature');
         insert into attributes values (117,200,'RD','Final Document');
         insert into attributes values (118,200,'RD','Final Document');
         insert into attributes values (119,201,'RMD','A400');
         insert into attributes values (120,201,'RMD','A500');
         end;
         /

        CREATE TABLE docs
        (
        obj_id NUMBER(4)
        );


        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO docs
        VALUES (100);

        INSERT INTO docs
        VALUES (104);

        INSERT INTO docs
        VALUES (109);

        INSERT INTO docs
        VALUES (117);

        INSERT INTO docs
        VALUES (118);

        INSERT INTO docs
        VALUES (119);

        INSERT INTO docs
        VALUES (120);  
        END;
        /


       CREATE TABLE attribute_types
       (
       attribute_type_id NUMBER(4),
       name_display_code VARCHAR2(5)
       );


       INSERT INTO attribute_types
       VALUES (200, 'RD');


       INSERT INTO attribute_types
       VALUES (201, 'RMD');
```

Comment: Do you want the "none of the above" jobs (`ordr = 6`) to be part of the results in any way? For example, if there's a job named `PROGRAMMER` how would that affect your results?

Comment: sorry... i forgot to put the filter like where job in (those 6 jobs.) , only 6 values needs to be pulled out.if you want i will update the query .

Comment: No need to do that yet; there may be another question or two. I'll see if I can come up with anything.

Comment: ravt - could you do as @EgorSkriptunoff requested below and post some sample data? Best to post a few `EMP` records and make sure at least two of them  have the same `job`, along with the expected results for the records you post.

Comment: HI i have added some sample data.

Comment: Hi @ravt - Sorry, I'm at work so I can't do a chat right now. I can look at this during my lunchtime, about 2 1/2 hours from now. If the results and data from your re-post match I may be able to help. Egor is awesome with these types of queries so you may hear from him too.

Comment: Hi gibbs... Egor provided me the output... thanks to both of you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH sta AS
  (SELECT 'Mature' "status1" FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'Review' FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'Final Draft' FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'Final Comment' FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'Final Document' FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'Archived' FROM DUAL)
SELECT 
  DECODE ("stat",
             'Mature', 'Mature Draft',
             'Review', 'Review',
             'Final Draft', 'Final Draft',
             'Final Comment', 'Final Comment',
             'Final Document', 'Final Document',
             'Archived', 'Archived Document'
  ) AS "progress_CMC_status",
  NVL("progress_cmc_status_numbers", 0) AS "progress_cmc_status_numbers",
  SUM (NVL("progress_cmc_status_numbers", 0)) OVER (ORDER BY 
            -DECODE ("stat",
            'Mature', 0,
            'Review', 1,
            'Final Draft', 2,
            'Final Comment', 3,
            'Final Document', 4,
            'Archived', 5,
            6) 
   ) AS "cmc_status_numbers"
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      "status1" AS "stat",
      "progress_cmc_status_numbers"
    FROM 
      sta
      LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT   
          VALUE AS "progress_CMC_status",
          COUNT (*) AS "progress_cmc_status_numbers"
        FROM ATTRIBUTES
        WHERE 
          attribute_type_id IN (
            SELECT attribute_type_id
            FROM attribute_types
            WHERE name_display_code = 'RD'
          )
          AND VALUE IN ('Mature', 'Review', 'Final Draft',
            'Final Comment', 'Final Document', 'Archived')
          AND object_id IN (SELECT obj_id FROM docs)
        GROUP BY VALUE
      ) a1 ON sta."status1" = a1."progress_CMC_status"
  )
  ORDER BY DECODE ("progress_CMC_status",
             'Mature Draft', 0,
             'Review', 1,
             'Final Draft', 2,
             'Final Comment', 3,
             'Final Document', 4,
             'Archived Document', 5,
             6)
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a43c3/3)

Comment: hi egor,  thanks for the answer. here i need left join to pull the missing data.

Comment: @ravt - Just replace your subquery (under LEFT JOIN) with my one.

Comment: hi, i tried but no luck.. suppose if job is having bonus <4000, then that is not participating in the cnt column. could you please look into that.

Comment: @ravt - I need sample data to understand what your problem is.

Comment: @ravt - You should calculate `sum() over()` in upper-level select.

Comment: hi i tried but it is giving error like not a single group group  function.

Comment: Hi Egor, how to check a condition like for Each of the statues (Mature, archive etc.) must be counted only if RMD value  is populated. i have tried keeping inner join in the last but i am not getting no values. even i tried the case statement . can you please give me any idea to achieve this.

Comment: @ravt - I'm afraid I not fully understand you.  Please open new question and provide sample data and desired result set.